# GraphServiceClient using authorization token / refresh token mechanism

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In my current application, I have created a refresh token / access token pair based on an authentication code I sent to my user. I continuously refresh this token (using said refresh token) to guarantee its integrity. When working directly with `msal`, I would get this token and pass it directly in the headers of my HTTP requests. I'm now migrating over to using the `msgraph` python sdk, and I cannot find a way of achieving this same flow using `azure.identity` in order to create a `GraphServiceClient` and make my requests.

I have at my disposal both the refresh and the access token, as well as the client id and secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up doing something fairly naive, but it works. YMMV though. Also of important consideration, this application works on delegated permissions, so no `ClientSecretCredentials` for me. I ended up creating something akin to:

```
class RawAccessTokenProvider:
    """
    A simple credential provider that returns a raw access token for use with Azure SDK clients.
    """

    def __init__(self, access_token: str, expires_on: int) -> None:
        self._access_token = access_token
        self._expires_on = expires_on

    def get_token(self, *scopes, **kwargs) -> AccessToken:
        return AccessToken(self._access_token, self._expires_on)
```

and using it like so:

```
    def get_client_by_token_credential(self, token, expires_on) -> GraphServiceClient:
        credentials = RawAccessTokenProvider(token, expires_on)
        return GraphServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
```

All the credit goes to the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/501#issuecomment-1941292450).